# Dictionaries overwriting in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

This program is to take the grammar rules found in Binary.text and store them into a dictionary, where the rules are:

```
N = N D
N = D
D = 0
D = 1
```

but the current code returns D: D = 1, N:N = D, whereas I want N: N D, N: D, D:0, D:1

```
import sys
import string

#default length of 3
stringLength = 3

#get last argument of command line(file)
filename1 = sys.argv[-1]


#get a length from user
try:
    stringLength = int(input('Length? '))
    filename = input('Filename: ')
except ValueError:
    print("Not a number")

#checks
print(stringLength)
print(filename)

def str2dict(filename="Binary.txt"):
    result = {}
    with open(filename, "r") as grammar:
        #read file 
        lines = grammar.readlines()
        count = 0
        #loop through
        for line in lines:
            print(line)
            result[line[0]] = line
            print (result)
    return result

print (str2dict("Binary.txt"))
```

Comment: Your  grammar rules are unclear: since you're assigning the same parameter twice, the last assignment takes over (a dictionary can save only one value per key).

Comment: I know this is the problem, how do I make it so that it will not overwrite and instead create a new entry with the same key?

Comment: What is your .txt file looks like?

Comment: Before you insert to the dictionary, check if a value already exists for this key, if it does, save both the old & new value in a list.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, **your data structure of choice is wrong**. Dictionary in python is a simple key-to-value mapping. What you'd like is a map from a key to multiple values. For that you'll need:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
```

Next, where are you splitting on '=' ? You'll need to do that in order to get the proper key/value you are looking for? You'll need

```
key, value = line.split('=', 1) #Returns an array, and gets unpacked into 2 variables
```

---

Putting the above two together, you'd go about in the following way:

```
result = defaultdict(list)
with open(filename, "r") as grammar:
    #read file 
    lines = grammar.readlines()
    count = 0
    #loop through
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
        key, value = line.split('=', 1)
        result[key.strip()].append(value.strip())
return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries, by definition, cannot have duplicate keys. Therefor there can only ever be a single 'D' key. You could, however, store a list of values at that key if you'd like. Ex:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# rest of your code...

result = defaultdict(list) # Use defaultdict so that an insert to an empty key creates a new list automatically
with open(filename, "r") as grammar:
    #read file 
    lines = grammar.readlines()
    count = 0
    #loop through
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
        result[line[0]].append(line)
        print (result)
return result
```

This will result in something like:

```
{"D" : ["D = N D", "D = 0", "D = 1"], "N" : ["N = D"]}
```

Comment: That is not the output OP is expecting. He wants to further split on '=' character.

Comment: That wasn't clear from their question + code (they specifically stated the problem was the lack of duplicate keys, not the format of the values), so I left it out rather than assuming. I simply solved the problem they described, rather than additional problems.